# Java native code

Tags: raspbian, java

I'm interested is it possible to compile Java code to native code so that I can run it on some cheap board like Arduino or Raspberry pi?

What compiler can you recommend?

Comment: Yes you can run java on the Raspberry Pi. It is like any other Linux computer that way. I don't know of any Java support for the arduino.

Comment: There are two JDKs available I'm aware of, Oracle 8 for ARM, and the open source Iced Tea that's in the Raspbian repos.

Comment: @SteveRobillard - There is [JArduino](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/JArduino) which might fit the bill.

Comment: @Greenonline thanks, note I did say I didn't know of any but I do now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can compile java code to native for example using `gcj` and run it on Raspberry Pi. But you can also run a complete java stack on the pi, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the Arduino, you could take a look at *[JArduino](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/JArduino)* library, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023640/control-an-arduino-with-java/16262362#16262362) to [Control an Arduino with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023640/control-an-arduino-with-java). It provides a Blink example written in Java.

You *will* need to update the Arduino firmware first though:

> Before using JArduino, please make sure your Arduino board contains the JArduino firmware:
>
> 1. Copy the JArduino folder (located in the distribution in `org.sintef.jarduino.samples/arduino`) into `/libraries/`
> 2. Launch your Arduino environment
> 3. File -> Examples -> JArduino -> JArduino firmware. It should open an Arduino program that you should upload to your board using the normal Arduino procedure.
> 4. Your Arduino board is now ready for Jarduino. You can exit the Arduino environment forever and launch Eclipse. Just run the Java/JArduino program.